# Hide the time indicator in Apple TV app using TVML / TVJS

Tags: tvos

I have a TVML-driven app and am looping a video with this code:

```
player.addEventListener("mediaItemWillChange", function(e) {
   player.playlist.push( mediaItem );
});
```

It works fine except that when it reaches the end and starts over, this appears:

[image]

The same thing happens if I add more of the same media item to the playlist and get it to loop that way.

Is there some way to hide it?